# Transformer core (eddy + hysteresis) losses

Tags: transformer

The question is:

[image]

The solution is:

[image]

However, Transformer core Losses

[image]

For Eddy current losses I think they will not change.
For the Hysteresis losses the flux is raised to a power greater than 1, so, I think it would actually reduce.

right?

Comment: The answer (c) is wrong. Using a transformer at double its intended frequency means it's less likely to saturate - it will take double the nameplate voltage for the same core flux, or half the flux at the same voltage. Hysteresis losses will reduce if n is >1, eddy current losses should stay similar.

Comment: As Neil points out, the included question image is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: Yep... all alternatives are wrong. The statement must have some misunderstanding.